# Google BigQuery Results Don't Show

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I created a python script that pushes a pandas dataframe into Google BigQuery and it looks as though I'm able to query the table directly from GBQ. However, another user is unable to view the results when they query from that same table I generated on GBQ. This seems to be a Big Query issue because when they tried to connect to GBQ and query the table indirectly using pandas, it seemed to work fine `(pd.read_gbq("SELECT * FROM ...", project_id))`. What is causing this strange behaviour?

What I'm seeing: [image]

What they are seeing:

[image]

Comment: Has your colleague refreshed their browser?  If it does show up in the resources pane, can they view the schema and/or use the preview tool?  Are you both in the same region?  Did you add any special configs to your python script?  It seems odd that their query did scan data (6.5KB) and also didn't error out.

Comment: Riley, if another user switch to the "Job Information" tab, do they see "Destination table" being a "temporary table"? If yes, could they click on the table to see its schema and more importantly on table's "detail" tab, how many rows are in that table?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this when loading tables to BigQuery via Python GBQ. If you take the following steps, the table will display properly

1. Load dataframe to BigQuery via Python GBQ
2. `SELECT * FROM uploaded_dataset.uploaded_dataset`; doing so will properly show the table
3. Within the BigQuery UI, save the table (as a new table name)

From there, you will be able to see the table properly. Unfortunately, I don't know how to resolve this without a manual step in the UI.